# PHP Email List Subscriber Script

Tags: php, forms, email, subscriber

Why won't this script work? I just want an email sent to hello@weblabcompany.com with the email of the subscriber so I can follow up with them later

```
<div class="col-2" id="sub-box">
                <h1 class="text-white margin-bottom"> Subscribe to Web Lab </h1>
                <h2 class="text-white margin-bottom"> Receive articles as they are published </h2>
                <form name="subscribe" action="/submail.php" method="post"> <input type="email" value="Email"> <input type="submit" value="Send" class="width-25"> </form>
            </div>


    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


 // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "hello@weblabcompany.com";

$email_subject = "New Sub";

function died($error) {

// your error code can go here

echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

echo $error."<br /><br />";

echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

die();

}


!isset($_POST['email']) 

 {

died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}



$email = $_POST['email']; // required


//$error_message = "";

//$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

//if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

//$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

//}

//$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

//if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

//$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

//}

//if(!preg_match($string_exp,$email)) {

//$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

//}

//if(strlen($message) < 2) {

//$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

//}
//if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

//died($error_message);

//}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";    

function clean_string($string) {

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}


$email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email);  

?>

 <!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. 

<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the  input's `name` attribute set to `email`.

Comment: Thanks I missed that, still not working though

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp <-- check that page out. also `died` is not a function. `die` is.